# Web Inspector quickly inspect element

Tags: keyboard, safari, web-inspector

How do I quickly inspect an element using Safari's Web Inspector, preferably by keyboard shortcut?

### Expected functionality

In Chrome, <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> enables the function and the mouse then selects an element.

### How things work in Safari

In Safari, the same combo seems to work, but only if Web Inspector is selected. Here are some example scenarios:

1. Web Inspector is not open. Pressing <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> does nothing.
2. Web Inspector is not open. Pressing <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> opens and selects Web Inspector, so following up with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> enables inspection mode.
3. Web Inspector is open, but user has interfaced with web site and Web Inspector is not selected. Pressing <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> does nothing and pressing <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> closes Web Inspector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click an element, then choose Inspect Element. This opens the developer tools and selects the element in the DOM. This can be scripted with Automator/Keyboard Maestro/etc for activation with a keyboard shortcut if you wish.

Comment: I had forgotten about Automator/etc. I'll mark this as accepted in a few hours if no native keyboard answers pop up.